# Testflight SDK version not updating in project

Tags: ios, testflight

I recently downloaded Testflight SDK version 3.0 and added header files in the project as shown in https://www.testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/3.0.0/. Previously I was using SDK 2.1.4

But when I archive the app and try to upload it to Testflight it still shows me my previous SDK version 2.1.4. I dont know whats the issue, i tried so many times but the sdk is still not updating to 3.0 in my project.

Comment: Did you drag into your project folder???

Comment: Yes, i have tried both dragging into project and also adding new file from menu.

Comment: Is file added or not??

Comment: Yes all testflight header files from sdk3.0 are added to the project otherwise it would give an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into and fixed this problem. In my case, the library search paths were pointing to the wrong place (with an older version of the library). Search for "Tetflight" in your Build Settings and delete or change any incorrect paths.

Comment: In my case I had renamed my project folder, so the library search path was still pointing to the files in my old directory.

Answer (score 2):

Only adding the header files is not enough. You also need to update `libTestFlight.a` to the latest version. Replace the older static library with the new one. Also make sure it is properly linked (Project, Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries). Then clean the project, rebuild, and you should be fine.

If you already did that, you should say so in your question. Now you only mention header files. But based on your description it could be that you are still linking an older version of the TestFlight static library.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue first from the question, but then immediately couldn't upload my ipa into TF because it contained the SDK.  TestFlight appears to be purchased by Apple and also TF has since removed support for Android.

[TestFlight does not accept builds with TestFlight SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222643/testflight-does-not-accept-builds-with-testflight-sdk)