# TestFlight does not accept builds with TestFlight SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, testflight

Trying to upload build with TF SDK I see the following error message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting any new builds that use TestFlight SDK. Please, remove SDK and re-upload.

Does anybody know any information about this? How long it will be like that? Will it be fixed? Am I doing something wrong? Interesting, that in another TF team everything is ok and upload with SDK goes with success.

Comment: check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983097/testflight-cannot-upload-build-cannot-download-sdk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TestFlight was acquired by Apple.  Android has also been disabled for TestFlight.

See the news [here](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/).

Don't worry about it. Use another mobile beta testing like

1. [Ubertesters](http://ubertesters.com/)
2. [Hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/)
3. [Mobtest](http://www.mobtest.com/)
4. [Centercode](http://www.centercode.com/)
5. [Appmuse](http://appmuse.com/)
6. [AppHost](https://appho.st/)
7. [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)

Comment: Hockeyapp is the best :))

Answer (score 5):

Burly the parent company of TestFlight was acquired by Apple a couple of weeks back. TF accepts uploads with SDK for older teams, if it is a new team that option is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

You can still distribute builds to testers though. Just remove TestFlight SDK and remove takeOff code and upload it without SDK. Obviously you lose all the SKD features, but at least you can distribute.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official announcement from TestFlight.
http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1452760

If you are using the SDK for crash log reporting, have a look at Crashlytics (owned by Twitter and completely free).

Comment: Also completely beta with invite only access :(